# classLoader.getResource(".") is /bin folder

Tags: java, classloader

I have read at least 3 or 4 such questions here in Stackoverflow but suprisingly I couldn't manage to figure out what is wrong here. When I build my project , compiled classes are moved into folder *"/bin"* and when I try to use something like

```
 classLoader.getResource("/files/file1.txt")
```

Classloader can't find it because It considers *"path/to/projectName/bin"* as its root folder

```
 classLoader.getResource(".")
```

so that returns

> /path/to/projectName/projectName/bin

not

> /path/to/projectName/projectName/

therefore I can't access */path/to/projectName/files/* folder . Any ideas what I'm making wrong here?

Comment: The `/files` folder is not on the classpath and therefore not available from the `ClassLoader`. Get them directly from the file system or put them on the class path.

Answer (score 4):

Apart for incorrectly reading the documentation, you're not doing anything wrong. The ClassLoader loads resources from the classpath, and can thus only load resources from directories and jars that are in the classpath.

If you want to read files from arbitrary locations, then use File IO, and not ClassLoader methods.

Answer (score 2):

If the files you are loading are resources like configuration etc, you could add the `files` folder on classpath and search for the file with its name directly

```
classLoader.getResource("file1.txt");
```

If its just arbitrary files and you do not want to provide the absolute path for portability reasons, you could try loading the file using File API by giving relative path.

```
File file = new File("files/file1.txt");
```